# Characteristic equation for 2-nd order ODE

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, determinant

Given a differential equation $\dot x = Ax$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we define its characteristic equation as $\chi(\lambda) = \det (\lambda I - A)$. Consider now the second order ODE
$$
  \ddot x + A x + B \dot x = 0, \;\;\; x \in \mathbb{R}^n
$$
With substitution $u = x$, $v = \dot x$ we can rewrite this ODE as a system
$$
  \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
  \dot u & = & v \\
  \dot v & = & -Au - Bv.
  \end{array}\right.
$$
This is an ODE with matrix
$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
     0 & I \\
     -A & -B
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
and hence with characteristic equation
$$
   \chi(\lambda) = \det \begin{bmatrix} \lambda I & - I \\ A & \lambda 
I+B\end{bmatrix}
.
$$
I know that there is a representation of such determinant as a determinant of $n \times n$ matrix with $a_{ii} + \lambda^2$ on the diagonal. How to obtain such representation? How to find off-diagonal items explicitly?

Comment: I thought your question was about ODEs but seems to be about matrices!

Comment: @Mercy you're right, I corrected tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have for block matrices, with $A$ invertible, that 
$$\pmatrix{A&B\\ C&D}=\pmatrix{A&0\\ C&I}\cdot\pmatrix{I&A^{-1}B\\0&D-CA^{-1}B}.$$
In our case, when $\lambda\neq 0$, we get 
$$\chi(\lambda)=\lambda^n\det\left(\lambda I+B-A\frac 1{\lambda}I(-I)\right)=\lambda^n\det(\lambda I+B+\frac 1{\lambda} A)=\det(\lambda^2I+\lambda B+A).$$

Comment: Thank you. I think that your formula works fine if $\det A = 0$. In this case we have to replace $A^{-1}$ by its pseudoinverse. Isn't it?

Comment: In fact my notation is quite confusing, since the $A$ in the general formula is not the same as the $A$ in your problem.

Comment: I know, it's just a general question.

Comment: You meant in the general formula? I think yes, there should be more general equations.